# Tensorflow: how to use RNN initial state in an estimator with different batch size for training and testing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a Tensorflow estimator using RNN (GRUCell).
I use zero_state to initialize the first state, it requires a fixed size.
My problem is that I want to be able to use the estimator to predict with a single sample (batchsize=1).
When it load the serialized estimator, it complain that the size of the batch I use for prediction does not match the training batch size.

If I reconstruct the estimator with a different batch size, I cannot load what has been serialized.

Is there an elegant way to use zero_state in an estimator?
I saw some solutions using a variable to store batch size, but using feed_dict method. I don't find how to make it work in the context of an estimator.

Here is the core of my simple test RNN in the estimator:

```
cells = [  tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self.getNSize()) for _ in range(self.getNLayers())]


multicell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=False)
H_init = tf.Variable( multicell.zero_state( batchsize, dtype=tf.float32 ), trainable=False)
H = tf.Variable( H_init )

Yr, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, Xo, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=H)
```

Would someone have a clue on that?

EDIT:

Ok, I try various things on this problem.
I now try to filter the variables I load from the checkpoint to remove 'H', which is used as internal state of the recurrent cells. For prediction, I can leave it with all 0 values.

So far, I did that:
First I define a hook:

```
class RestoreHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self, init_fn):
        self.init_fn = init_fn

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord=None):
        print("--------------->After create session.")
        self.init_fn(session)
```

Then in my model_fn:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

        # Do not restore H as it's batch size might be different.
        vlist = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore()
        vlist = [ x for x in vlist if x.name.split(':')[0] != 'architecture/H']
        init_fn = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.modelDir), vlist, ignore_missing_vars=True)
        spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          predictions = {
                                              'logits': logits,
                                          },
                                          export_outputs={
                                              'prediction': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput( logits )
                                          },
                                          prediction_hooks=[RestoreHook(init_fn)])
```

I took this piece of code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14713

But it does not work yet. It seems that it still trying to load H from the file... I checked that it is not in vlist.
I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get batch size form other tensor [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/35dface2e1aadbd4bd3b83e00618fda24c89f7d4/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/kernel_tests/attention_wrapper_test.py#L96)

`decoder_initial_state = cell.zero_state(array_ops.shape(attention_states)[0], 
                                dtypes.float32).clone(cell_state=encoder_state)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does not solve the problem as the sizes of the batches will be different while training and predicting. So, the size of the internal state of the RNN will be serialized with a given size, then a size mismatch will happen when reloading. That is why I try to filter out the this 'H' variable when reloading the checkpoint. It would initialized with the zero_state based on the input batch size, and not overwritten by the checkpoint loading.

Comment: I use different batch sizes for training , evaluating and inferencing it works fine without explicitly removing batch sizes when loading checkpoints.BTW i use TensorFlow 1.11.0-rc0 , you can use tf-nightly or tf-nightly-gpu to get that version

Comment: How do you initialize the initial_state parameter?

Comment: Switching to 1.11 did not change anything. The initial state is saved with a given size (that depends on the batch size) and expect the same size when loaded. I makes the whole network dependent of the batch size. Very annoying. Has someone found a solution ?

Comment: look at this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/ . Like that you need to have different graphs for training , evaluation , testing when you are using tensorflow  , look here:https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#building-training-eval-and-inference-graphs

Comment: If you have any small reproducible code , i'm happy to help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The trick was to create both initial states, one for training and one for prediction with different batch sizes, and have them serialized by the estimator. Then use the is_training condition to use the first or second variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- I create the variables for the initial state for both batchsize=64 and batchsize=1.
- At training I use the first one to initialize the RNN.
- At Predict time, I use the second one.

It works as both those variables will be serialized and restored by the estimator code so it will not complain.
The drawback is that the query batch size (in my case, 1) bust be known at training time (when it create both variables).